# AtomicIntegerArray versus BitSet in terms of performance

Tags: java, parallel-processing, bitset, atomicinteger

I wanted to ask about the **efficiency** of using `AtomicIntegerArray` and `BitSet`, and which one has better performance when used in parallel stream java?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This will depend a lot on the use case. You need to be more specific than that. What kind of performance are you interested in? Memory? Runtime?

Comment: Also, they are not really comparable semantically, as "A BitSet is not safe for multithreaded use without external synchronization." [JavaDocs for BitSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html), while "An int array in which elements may be updated atomically." [AtomicIntegerArray](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html)

Comment: Please add a concrete example of what you are trying to do, and explain what kind of performace characteristics you are interested in.

Comment: @Hulk Thank you.  I want to improve performance (running time) of my algorithm. I want to perform a set of computations for nodes in a network, and schedule them in parallel to do the computations. At each step of my algorithm a specif set of vertices should be scheduled for computation. I need AtomicIntegerArray/BitSet to keep track of such nodes.